# Write a program to find all twin primes less than 1,000. Display the output as follows: (3,5) (5,7)

Tags: java, primes

I am currently trying to write a program to find
all twin primes less than 1,000. And then display the output as follows (3,5)(5,7).....(etc)

So far I only have the code to find prime numbers, and am unsure as to what I should do to not only find the twin prime numbers, but how to print all of them properly.  Any advice is very appreciated, and a big thank you in advance!  Here is my code so far.

```
   int a =0;
   int b =0;
   String d = "";
   for (a = 1; a <= 100; a++) {               
     int counter = 0;     
     for (b = a; b >= 1; b--) {
       if (a % b == 0) {
         counter = counter + 1;
       }
     }
     if (counter == 2) {
       w = w + a + " ";
       // ..
```

Comment: You really do not have an idea? How long did you think about it?

Comment: If you need information later you will  need to save it.

Comment: Wow what a coincidence this is exactly the assignment that I got in high school in computer science class

Comment: I am not in high school, and have not been for years now but appreciate the negative feedback.  I hope you you enjoy wasting your time, because that's what you just did shady330.  Also, thank you Thorbjorn.  I am new to java so I am trying to get a grasp on the basics and I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check [this](http://www.guideforschool.com/1933937-java-program-to-print-twin-prime-numbers-within-a-range/) out. It asks for input, but change `p` to `1`and `q` to `100` (inside `main`). And then remove line numbers `30-33`. It also prints out the twin prime numbers as you wanted it.

Comment: This made the most sense to me, I am going to try and write that in my own way, but I was having trouble figuring out how to only pull the twin primes.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Using the definition

> Twin Prime numbers are a pair of numbers which are both prime and
>   their difference is 2.

the problem is mostly determining all prime numbers between 1 and 1000 and then looking for twins in the above sense.

A simple method to determine primes of such a small interval is the Sieve of Eratosthenes. It runs in O(n log log n) operations and needs O(n) memory.

But even if you do not know this method, you might succeed to brute-force this problem instance of n = 1000, a simple division should reveal all prime numbers in [1,n] in about O(n^2) operations.

Answer (score 0):

//Concept is every prime number is of the form ( 6n-1 ) or ( 6n+1 ) form except 2 and 3

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std; 
int fact(unsigned long long int );
int main(){
unsigned long long int n;
cout<<"Enter the number upto which you want prime numbers\n";
cin>>n;
cout<<"List of prime number is as follows"<<endl;
cout<<"(3,5)";

for(unsigned long long int i=5;i<=n;i+=6){  
    int d,e;
    d=fact(i);
    e=fact((i+2));
    if(d==1 && e==1)
        cout<<",("<<i<<","<<(i+2)<<")";
 } 
cout<<"\n";
return 0;
}
int fact(unsigned long long int x){
    if(x%2==0 || x%3==0)
        return 0;
    for(unsigned long long int j=5;j*j<=x;j+=6)         
    {   
        if(x%j==0 || x%(j+2)==0)
            return 0;
    }
return 1;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, your explanation is a little over my head.  But hopefully I will understand this more now that I have two different ways of going about it.  Thanks again

Comment: By the way, this is supposed to be java.

Answer (score 0):

Heres my code for twin prime in blue java.

But how to print it in correct order and less than 100.

```
public class twin_prime
{
    public static void main(int n)
    {
        int i,j;
        int p=n;
        int q=n+2;
        int c=0;
        int co=0;
        int f=q;
        System.out.println(" the no you had input is "+n);
        System.out.println("the second number will be taken at a difference of 2 ");
        System.out.println("the second number is :"+q);
        for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
        {
            if(p%i==0)
            {
                c=c+1;
            }
        }
        if(c==2)
        {
            System.out.println("no. is prime");
        }
        for(j=1;j<=q;j++)
        {
            if(f%j==0)
            {
                co=co+1;
            }
        }
        if(co==2)
        {
            System.out.println("no. is twin prime");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I dunno This code will able to solve to your problem. If I understand your task then this code can help to you. (Sorry. My English is not so good!) I hope I could help to you.

```js
public class twinPrime {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        int ct=0, n=0, i=1, j=1, db=0;
        int[] array= new int[25]; //  1 between 100 there are 25 pieces 

        System.out.println("Twin primes paires:");
        while(n<array.length) {
                j=1;
                ct=0;
                while(j<=i) {
                    if(i%j==0) {
                        ct++;
                    }
                    j++;                
                }
                if(ct==2) {
                    //System.out.println(i);  
                    array[n]=i; //All prime numbers between 1-100
                    n++;
                }
            i++;    
            }
        for( int a=0; a<array.length-1;a++) { //You need array.length-1 because You won't able to array[26]-array[27] because array[27] doesn't exist
            //System.out.println("Prime Numbers:"+array[a]);
            if(array[a]-array[a+1]==-2) {
                db++;
                System.out.println(array[a]+"\t|\t"+array[a+1]);
            }   
        }
        System.out.println("Number of TwinPrime: "+db);
        
    }
        
  }
```